# How to use a global Component with React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React Component say DownloadProgress which has to persist across various Containers. This Component is reading from my store written in Redux and accordingly performing some actions.

I am initialising it as follows from my Container:

```
 download() {
   const filter = this.props.filter
   this.props.dispatch(merchantExcelQueue(filter,'transactions'));
    this.setState({
    showDownloadProgress: true
  })

}
render() {
 if(this.state.showDownloadProgress) {
   downloadProgress = (<DownloadProgress/>)
}
}
```

How do I persist this Component when my route changes. Please help

Comment: The idea is, first you need to move `shouldDownloadProgress` to redux state, then move download progress to the top of your Component wrapper.

Comment: @AlfredCrosby How does one move the component top of your Component wrapper? I understand the redux part.

Comment: As in, once `showDownloadProgress` is in redux, you can just drop your download component in a page level component shared by all the pages that need it. And the page level component is what your container renders. Think navigation.

Comment: @PhilHauser Got it thanks

Comment:  no problem. Good luck